# How to create a power bi report with excel which updates on daily basis

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Hi I have an excel which is saved in one drive for business. I update the file on daily basis with the agent name, date and no of clients handled. I have created a report with power bi file in desktop version and published it in power bi online and then created link by publish to web option. Now this link is not updated with recent data.

I tried to create the report through power bi online but it does not have options like modeling and query editor...

I am very new to power bi so kindly excuse for any  errors ....

I just need to give the operations team a link to view daily performance of the team, rather than opening excel file and looking at the data.

I just need to paste the data in excel file and the report should be updated automatically ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created a report with power bi file in desktop version and published it in power bi online and then created link by publish to web option.

Creating the report in Power BI Desktop is the correct first step. But if you are using [Publish to Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) functionality, you are publicly sharing your data in an insecure manner. Do you actually mean Publish To Web, or do you just mean that you published your report to PowerBI.com?

> Now this link is not updated with recent data.

You need to set a [scheduled refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh) so the Power BI model will contain the latest version of the data from your Excel file. You can also manually refresh your dataset, but if you want to make sure it has the latest data every day, scheduled refresh is the way to go. Locate your dataset in PowerBI.com. There will be a scheduled refresh option. On the settings page, enter your credentials, then under scheduled refresh turn on the Keep your data up to date toggle. Choose a frequency and time.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-onedrive-business-links#use-the-link-in-power-bi-desktop) to make sure you connected to your file in OneDrive correctly that also mentions how to set up scheduled refresh at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!! The data is just name and numbers and i have the permission to publish to web. Actually i have already visited the links you provided but I am unable to get it. So shall we go step by step. First I have created the report in powerbi desktop the source file is from one drive. Second i click on the publish option in powerbi desktop and get the report published to powerbi online. Thrid from power bi online i click publish to web option to generate a link.  Now if I make changes(like update everyday's data) in excel sheet will it updated on the embedded code.

Comment: It will if you refresh your dataset, either manually or through scheduled refresh.

Comment: Correct. Refresh in PowerBI.com.